# What is the difference between using a cross join and putting a comma between the two tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, select

What is the difference between

```
select * from A, B
```

and

```
select * from A cross join B
```

? They seem to return the same results.

Is the second version preferred over the first? Is the first version completely syntactically wrong?

Comment: Cartesian products are almost never useful...

Comment: But in the rare cases that they are, it's nice to know the proper way to write them.

Comment: Rarely useful, but probably exist at least once in every major project.

Comment: There is actually a lot of uses for cross joins, e.g. to generate sample data or in geographic information processing (PostGIS). I use it a lot, e.g. to calculate distances (ST_Distance) between one point cross joining it to other points...

Comment: It’s a nice notion to unnest arrays and structs in BigQuery

Answer (score 54, accepted):

They return the same results because they are semantically identical.  This:

```
select * 
  from A, B
```

...is (wince) SQL-89 syntax.  Without a WHERE clause to link the tables together, the result is a Cartesian product.  Which is exactly what alternative provides as well:

```
    select * 
      from A 
cross join B
```

...but the CROSS JOIN is SQL-92 syntax.

### About Performance

There's no performance difference between them.

### Why Use SQL-92?

The reason to use SQL-92 syntax is for OUTER JOIN support (IE: LEFT, FULL, RIGHT)--SQL-89 syntax doesn't have any, so many databases implemented their own (which doesn't port to any other databases).  IE: Oracle's `(+)`, SQL Server's `=*`

Comment: Although this is an old post, purely for the record: there is a difference when another join or cross apply is used (http://stackoverflow.com/a/31441463/1431042 )

Answer (score 15):

Stumbled upon this post from another SO question, but a big difference is the linkage cross join creates. For example using `cross apply` or another join after `B` on the first ('comma') variant, the cross apply or join would only refer to the table(s) after the dot. e.g, the following:

```
select * from A, B join C on C.SomeField = A.SomeField and C.SomeField = B.SomeField
```

would create an error:

> The multi-part identifier "A.SomeField" could not be bound.

because the join on C only scopes to B, whereas the same with cross join...

```
select * from A cross join B join C on C.SomeField = A.SomeField and C.SomeField = B.SomeField
```

..is deemed ok. The same would apply if `cross apply` is used. For example placing a cross apply on a function after `B`, the function could only use fields of B, where the same query with cross join, could use fields from both A and B.
Of course, this also means the reverse can be used as well. If you want to add a join solely for one of the tables, you can achieve that by going 'comma' on the tables.

Comment: Found the same some minutes ago... Good to add this here!

Answer (score 12):

Besides brevity (favoring `,`) and consistency (favoring `CROSS JOIN`), the sole difference is precedence.

The comma is lower precedence than other joins.

---

For example, the explicit form of

```
SELECT *
FROM a
  CROSS JOIN b
  JOIN c ON a.id = c.id
```

is

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  a
  CROSS JOIN b
)
  INNER JOIN c ON a.id = c.id
```

which is valid.

Whereas the explicit form of

```
SELECT *
FROM a,
  b
  JOIN c ON a.id = c.id
```

is

```
SELECT *
FROM a
  CROSS JOIN (
    b
    INNER JOIN c ON a.id = c.id
  )
```

which is invalid (the join clause references inaccessible `a`).

---

In your example, there are only two tables, so the two queries are exactly equivalent.

Answer (score 6):

They are the same and should (almost) never be used.

Comment: But if you *do* need to cross join them, please use the latter :-) It's quite silly that cross join got that shortcut notation.

Comment: I think the "shortcut notation" predates the cross join notation.

Comment: You're correct--`CROSS JOIN` became ANSI standard in SQL:1992, vs the ANSI SQL:1989 syntax using commas.

Answer (score 3):

The first version was originally the only way to join two tables. But it has a number of problems so the JOIN keyword was added in the ANSI-92 standard. They give the same results but the second is more explicit and is to be preferred.

Answer (score 2):

To add to the answers already given:

```
select * from A, B
```

This was the only way of joining prior to the 1992 SQL standard. So if you wanted an inner join, you'd have to use the `WHERE` clause for the criteria:

```
select * from A, B
where A.x = B.y;
```

One problem with this syntax was that there was no standard for outer joins. Another was that this gets unreadable with many tables and is hence prone to errors and less maintainable.

```
select * from A, B, C, D
where B.id = C.id_b
and C.id_d = D.id;
```

Here we have a cross join of A with B/C/D. On purpose or not? Maybe the programmer just forgot the `and B.id = A.id_b` (or whatever), or maybe this line was deleted by mistake, and maybe still it was really meant to be a cross join.  Who could say?

Here is the same with explicit joins

```
select * 
from A
cross join B
inner join C on C.id_b = B.id
inner join D on D.id = C.id_d;
```

No doubt about the programmers intentions anymore.

The old comma-separated syntax was replaced for good reasons and should not be used anymore.

Comment: @Quazi Irfan: Is this a joke question? This is exactly what I have answered above.

Answer (score 1):

These are the examples of implicit and explicit cross joins. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Cross_join.

Comment: I disagree that they are explicit/implicit--both are ANSI standard, and the ANSI-89 format is considered deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

To the comments as to the utility of cross joins, there is one very useful and valid example of using cross joins or commas in the admittedly somewhat obscure world of Postgres generate_series and Postgis spatial sql where you can use a cross join against generate_series to extract the nth geometry out of a Geometry Collection or Multi-(Polygon/Point/Linestring), see: http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.4/ST_GeometryN.html

```
SELECT n, ST_AsEWKT(ST_GeometryN(the_geom, n)) As geomewkt
  FROM (
    VALUES (ST_GeomFromEWKT('MULTIPOINT(1 2 7, 3 4 7, 5 6 7, 8 9 10)') ),
          ( ST_GeomFromEWKT('MULTICURVE(CIRCULARSTRING(2.5 2.5,4.5 2.5, 3.5 3.5), (10 11, 12 11))') )
    )  As foo(the_geom)
CROSS JOIN generate_series(1,100) n
  WHERE n <= ST_NumGeometries(the_geom);
```

This can be very useful if you want to get the area, centroid, bounding box or many of the other operations you can perform on a single geometry, when they are contained within a larger one.

I have always written such queries using a comma before generate_series, until one day when I wondered if this really meant cross join, which brought me to this post. Obscure, but definitely useful.