# How efficient is a cross-join in Linq-to-SQL?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I know that if you use Linq-to-objects to perform a cross-join, the inner sequence is iterated once for each element of the outer sequence.

The following code demonstrates the multiple iteration of `ints2`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            var ints1 = Ints1();
            var ints2 = Ints2();

            var test = from i in ints1
                       from j in ints2
                       select i*j;

            foreach (var i in test)
                Console.WriteLine(i);
        }

        private static IEnumerable<int> Ints1()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Starting  Ints1()");

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
                yield return i;

            Console.WriteLine("Ending Ints1()");
        }

        private static IEnumerable<int> Ints2()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Starting Ints2()");

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
                yield return i;

            Console.WriteLine("Ending Ints2()");
        }
    }
}
```

My question is this:

If you do the same sort of query in Linq-to-SQL, will it be optimised to a SQL `CROSS JOIN`? Or will it evaluate the inner sequence multiple times (or do some other thing)?

(I'm almost certain that it will be optimised, but after searching the 'net I have failed to find any conclusive documentation about this.)

---

[EDIT]

I just wanted to mention the reason I'm asking this question.

`Resharper` normally warns you if you iterate over an IEnumerable twice, but it *doesn't* warn you if you use a nested `from` to perform a cross-join (such as in my sample code above).

I wondered why it didn't warn you, and decided it was probably due to one of two reasons:

Either it was an oversight, or it didn't need to because multiple enumeration isn't a problem for nested `from` because it gets turned into an efficient operation in Linq-to-SQL. I'm thinking it's for the latter reason.

Now you might wonder if `Resharper` should still warn anyway because Linq-to-objects *will* enumerate the inner sequence multiple times - but I guess that's much less serious.

Also, I am never *actually* performing such cross-joins on a database (nor do I intend to), but I *have* used them in Linq-to-objects.

Comment: Why don't you try it and look at the generated query?

Comment: @ThomasLevesque I would if I knew how :)

Comment: @MatthewWatson Use Sql Server Profiler, This [Tutorial](https://www.sellsbrothers.com/posts/Details/12698) has a more detailed guide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Linq-to-SQL translates the linq query to T-SQL that runs on the *database side*.

For example, if you write:

```
from i in myContext.Table1
from j in myContext.Table2
select new {i,j}
```

Linq-to-SQL will translate that to a T-SQL query similar to:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1, Table2
```

and then it will serve the resulting anonymous type objects by iterating over the resultset *just once*.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: OK, so it doesn't use a `CROSS JOIN`, but it does something that is just as efficient - is that right?

Comment: yes, that is right. Of cource, this is a simple example, and I would question the efficiency of doing such a linq query... but the key is that it will generate a t-sql that runs remotely (it won't, for example, pull both lists to the client side and then do the join operation locally).

Comment: @MatthewWatson `... FROM Table1, Table2` [**is** (implicitly) a `CROSS JOIN`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3918570)