# Summation from 3 tables SQL

Tags: sql

I have 4 tables that carry the following schema:

- **Product** (maker, model, type)
- **PC** (model, speed, ram, hd, price)
- **Laptop** (model, speed, ram, hd, screen, price)
- **Printer** (model, color,type, price)

Say I need to buy a PC, a Laptop, and a Printer all within a budget of $2K.
What query should I use to find all of the available options that are underneath this 
budget?

Obviously for this problem I would need to look at all of the model `#'s` of
PCs, Laptops, and Printers, and filter out the respective prices for
each of those products.

But I'm not quite too sure what would be needed in my where clause
to do this correctly.

```
select Product.model
from Product, PC, Laptop, Printer
where ... ???
```

Answer (score 2):

I would guess you coud to something along these lines to start

```
Select * 
From PC, Laptop, Printer
Where (PC.price + Laptop.price + Printer.price) <= 2000
```

The implied join "From PC, Laptop, Printer" would make all the combinations since there not "joining Where", and then you just select the combinations that match you pricing criteria.

Comment: Optimum method is table joining.

Comment: @Kaf No need for a join; we do a cartesian product to get all the combinations and then just filter the combinations on the total price.

Comment: @Colin'tHart, I meant about whether to use `From table1, table2` or `From table1 CROSS JOIN table2`. Yes people say there is [no performance wise difference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3918570/what-is-the-difference-between-using-a-cross-join-and-putting-a-comma-between-th).

Answer (score 0):

try

```
select Product.model
  from Product a, PC b, Laptop c, Printer d
 where a.model = b.model
   and a.model = c.model
   and a.model = d.model
   and b.model = c.model
   and b.model = d.model
   and c.model = d.model
```

This is a bad query, it is best to separate the query will get better performance

Answer (score 0):

```
select PC.Model, PC.Price, Laptop.Model, Laptop.Price, Printer.Model, Printer.Price
from PC, Laptop, Printer
where (PC.price + Laptop.Price + Printer.Price) <= 2000
```

Does this work for you?

Comment: It appears to work.
I would like to filter it down to just display the model numbers
and prices attached to them however.

I'm trying to avoid using select *

Comment: @MichaelGresham There, edited so that it fits your comment. Better?

Answer (score 0):

You can try CROSS JOIN or CROSS APPLY to get all the possible combinations and then filter out all that have price sum less than 2K$

Something like

`SELECT 

        *

FROM
        PC

        CROSS APPLY Laptop

        CROSS APPLY Printer

WHERE

        PC.price + Laptop.price + Printer.price < 2000`

Comment: Thanks everyone! I think I've figured it out on my own using a combination of the answers provided above.

I ended up settling with:

select distinct c.model, c.price, L.model, L.price, R.model, R.price from Product p, PC c join Laptop L join Printer R where (c.price + L.price + R.price) <= 2000;