# Please explain the SQL join

Tags: mysql, sql

I currently working on some legacy systems and I came across a piece of sql written like so:

```
SELECT 
    cel.id,
    cel.campaign_id,
    cel.campaign_name,
    cel.campaign_message_type,
    cel.responsible_user_id,
    cel.responsible_user_full_name,
    cel.person_id,
    cel.email_template_id,
    cel.email_message_subject,
    cel.recipient_list_name,
    cel.first_name,
    cel.last_name,
    cel.email_address,
    b.message_content_html email_message_content_html,
    b.message_content_text email_message_content_text,
    b.course_presentation_id,
    cp.phone_mobile
FROM 
    campaigns_email_logs cel

    LEFT JOIN contacts_people cp ON 
        (cel.person_id = c.id),
        campaigns_email b
WHERE 
    cel.campaign_id = b.id and 
    cel.status = 'queued' and 
    cel.datetime_start < now() and 
    cel.datetime_end > now() and 
    b.paused = 'no' 
order by 
    {$campaignMessagesToSendOrdering};
```

Please can you explain what the LEFT JOIN campaigns_email is doing? Is it doing a cross join on the contacts_people? For me to understand this quickly could any one please rewrite it without the ,campaigns_email.

I know you can have multiple tables in your from clause, but I have never seen it like this.

Thanks.

Comment: Here nobody will do your work for you, here people help you find solutions for Problem, you tried to solve. At least check the Dokumentation befor asking for help [Join Doku MySql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/join.html)

Comment: @winner_joiner where in the question is he asking you to do his work for him?

Comment: `any one please rewrite it without the ,campaigns_email.` - rewriting the query without that join means no more than removing this from the query: `, campaigns_email b`

Comment: @jerdiggity for me the Part "Please can you explain waht the LEFT JOIN ... is doing?" and "... could any one please rewrite it ...", seems a easy way out for not reading the Documentation and leting someone do the work, but it is only my opinion. Maybe i understood it wrong, my bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This query has a LEFT JOIN *and* a CROSS JOIN (using the ["comma syntax"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3918570/what-is-the-difference-between-using-a-cross-join-and-putting-a-comma-between-th)).

The relevant portion is semantically identical to:

```
FROM campaigns_email_logs cel
LEFT JOIN contacts_people cp ON (cel.person_id = cp.id)
CROSS JOIN campaigns_email b
```

So, now that we have it established as a CROSS JOIN, let's take the conditions into account:

```
WHERE2 cel.campaign_id = b.id ..
```

Boom. Right there we've turned this CROSS JOIN into an INNER JOIN. Rewriting:

```
FROM campaigns_email_logs cel
LEFT JOIN contacts_people cp ON (cel.person_id = cp.id)
JOIN campaigns_email b ON (cel.campaign_id = b.id)
```

Comment: Thank you all for the help. Incredible response. I thought it might be a cross join - I have just never seen it done like this. Sorry about the typo  "c.id" it should be "cp.id". I had to make it a little readable and forgot to update that.

Answer (score 0):

`campaigns_email` is not left-joined to anything.

In  your `FROM` clause you have a `JOIN` between `campaigns_email_logs` and `contacts_people`. Then you have a cartessian product with the result of this join and `campaigns_email`.