# Is a query with table separated by comma a cross join query?

Tags: sql, operation

I know some of SQL but, I always use `join`, `left`, `cross` and so on, but in a query where the tables are separated by a comma. It's looks like a cross join to me. But I don't know how to test it (the result is the same with the tries I made).

```
SELECT A.id, B.id
FROM A,B
WHERE A.id_B = B.id
```

Even in the great Question (with great answers) ["What is the difference between Left, Right, Outer and Inner Joins?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448023/what-is-the-difference-between-left-right-outer-and-inner-joins/448080#448080) I didn't find an answer to this.

Comment: I'm using Mysql at the moment. But I don't think this is relevant to the main point of the question.

Comment: The tables separate by comma is older syntax. For example prior to Oracle 9i, the syntax to perform joins was similar to the SQL statement you have above. This is an INNER JOIN example

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between using a cross join and putting a comma between the two tables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3918570/what-is-the-difference-between-using-a-cross-join-and-putting-a-comma-between-th)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It *would* be a cross join if there wasn't a `WHERE` clause relating the two tables.  In this case it's functionally equivalent to an inner join (matching records by `id_rel` and `id`)

It's an older syntax for joining tables that is still supported in most systems, but JOIN syntax is largely preferred.

Answer (score 2):

**This is old pre - 1992 standard SQL join syntax, which you should not mimic or use in anything you write today**

The `where` clause specifies the join style and columns.  You can use `=` or `*=` or`=*` in the where to make join, left or right joins. No joins in the `WHERE` make it a cross join.

Comment: Not even for a cross join (query without the `where`) ? (I don't like this syntax, but is good to know)

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have join criteria provided in the where clause, this syntax results in an inner join.  For example:

```
Where tableA.value = TableB.Value
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like an `INNER JOIN`

i.e. both sides must exist to get a result.

For example:

```
SELECT 
  A.id, B.id
FROM A
  INNER JOIN B ON A A.id_rel = B.id
```