# Cartesian product using sql server

Tags: sql-server, cartesian-product

I do have a problem regarding to Cartesian product using **SQL SERVER 2012**.

**Here's my sample query:**

```
SELECT A1.*
   ,RIGHT('00000' + A1.SampleID,5) AS [RealSampleID]

FROM
(
SELECT 
    ARS1.SampleID
   ,ARS1.SampleNo
FROM TblSamples AS ARS1
GROUP BY 
     ARS1.SampleNo
    ,ARS1.SampleID
) AS [A1]
INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT 
    ARS2.SampleID
   ,ARS2.SampleNo
FROM TblSamples AS ARS2
WHERE ISNUMERIC(ARS2.SampleID) = 0
GROUP BY 
     ARS2.SampleNo
    ,ARS2.SampleID
) AS A2
ON A1.SampleNo=A2.SampleNo
```

**Result of my Query**

[image]

**Expected Result:**

[image]

[Cartesian product Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product):
 non numeric **SampleID** X numeric **SampleID** per **SampleNo**

Example:

All SampleNo **137**. We have two Numeric values (277 and 278) in **SampleID** column and one distinct Non-Numeric value (R00137). Then RealSampleID of this non-Numeric value (R00137) will be 00277 and 00278. Just like what we have seen in the above image output.

Comment: Can you provide sample data for the two tables?

Comment: Try `ISNUMERIC(ARS2.SampleID) = 1` and also `RIGHT('00000' + A2.SampleID,5) AS [RealSampleID]` - you want table A2 to hold the 'correct' sampleIDs

Comment: `SELECT A1.*, RIGHT('00000' + A1.SampleID,5) AS [RealSampleID]` - all fields are prefixed A1, no A2; the bottom row in your expected result is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Without sample data, this may be not what you want, but this is Cartesian Product:

```
SELECT A1.*
   ,RIGHT('00000' + A1.SampleID,5) AS [RealSampleID]
FROM
(
SELECT 
    ARS1.SampleID
   ,ARS1.SampleNo
FROM TblSamples AS ARS1
GROUP BY 
     ARS1.SampleNo
    ,ARS1.SampleID
) AS [A1],
(
SELECT 
    ARS2.SampleID
   ,ARS2.SampleNo
FROM TblSamples AS ARS2
WHERE ISNUMERIC(ARS2.SampleID) = 0
GROUP BY 
     ARS2.SampleNo
    ,ARS2.SampleID
) AS A2
```

Comment: These days I'd recommend [using the ANSI standard `CROSS JOIN` syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3918570/what-is-the-difference-between-using-a-cross-join-and-putting-a-comma-between-th).