# How to use 2 reference tables to bind to a multiple data sets like a fact tables

Tags: sql-server

I am struggling with getting this bind properly.  I am trying to use 2 reference tables (Users & Time) to link to a transaction table that contains (Users, Time & Sum of transactions) but the binding keeps failing.  If I put both references tables in front, I get an error: "The multi-part identifier could not be bound".

```
DECLARE @Time table (workweek int) --Time table 1 - 52 for weekcode
DECLARE @DIRECT table (UserId int, WorkWeek int, [Hours] decimal(7,3)) --Direct data table, acts like a fact table
DECLARE @REG table (UserId int, WorkWeek int, [Hours] decimal(7,3)) --Reg data table, acts like a fact table

INSERT INTO @DIRECT
SELECT  
        f.userID [UserId]
        ,DATEPART(wk, t.DateOfService) [WorkWeek]
        ,SUM( ROUND( (DATEDIFF(SECOND, t.[TimeIn], t.[TimeOut]) / 3600.0), 2)) [Hours]
    FROM ...

INSERT INTO @REG
SELECT  
        f.userID [UserId]
        ,DATEPART(wk, t.DateOfService) [WorkWeek]
        ,SUM( ROUND( (DATEDIFF(SECOND, t.[TimeIn], t.[TimeOut]) / 3600.0), 2)) [Hours]
    FROM ...

SELECT  u.DisplayName
        ,t.workweek
        ,u.userId [EmployeeId]
        ,direct.[Hours] [Direct], reg.[Hours] [Regular]
        ,direct.[Hours]+reg.[Hours] [SumOfTime]
FROM    @Time t, Users u
LEFT JOIN @DIRECT direct on u.UserID = direct.UserId and t.workweek = direct.WorkWeek
LEFT JOIN @REG reg on u.UserID = reg.UserId and t.workweek = reg.WorkWeek
```

When I adjust to resolve errors, I get the data but the bind fails and the results should be 4 rows with of with but it comes out with multiples of the 4 rows.

Thanks for your help beforehand. I know I am just missing something simple but for some reason this is just not working out for me no matter what I do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you missed the `CROSS JOIN` between Time and User table. You can [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3918570/what-is-the-difference-between-using-a-cross-join-and-putting-a-comma-between-th/31441463#31441463) this post for difference between using `CROSS JOIN` syntax and comma between two tables.

```
SELECT  u.DisplayName
        ,t.workweek
        ,u.userId [EmployeeId]
        ,direct.[Hours] [Direct], reg.[Hours] [Regular]
        ,direct.[Hours]+reg.[Hours] [SumOfTime]
FROM    @Time t 
CROSS JOIN @Users u
LEFT JOIN @DIRECT direct on u.UserID = direct.UserId and t.workweek = direct.WorkWeek
LEFT JOIN @REG reg on u.UserID = reg.UserId and t.workweek = reg.WorkWeek
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
FROM @Time t
JOIN @Direct direct on t.workweek = direct.workweek
JOIN @Reg reg on t.workweek = reg.workweek
JOIN @users u on u.userid in (direct.userid, reg.userid)
```

Comment: This doesn't work in the multi data set instances b/c it doesn't join tightly enough.  I tried out the idea and it creates even more row duplication,

Comment: Not sure what you mean by join tightly enough.  There is no tighter join than an inner join.  What we need is some sample data and expected output, using that sample data.  Just fill in the ellipsis in your original post with data we can use.