# Get specific values from some tables in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables:

teams_world:

[image]

match_world:

[image]

resultat_world:

[image]

So I want to display the resultat of the match with specific details:

Currently I have this:

```
SELECT 
    resultat_world.id_match,
    team.nom AS team_winner, 
    resultat_world.score_home,
    resultat_world.score_away
  FROM 
    resultat_world 
  INNER JOIN 
  teams_world AS team 
    ON resultat_world.id_equipe_winner = team.id_equipe
```

[image]

So now, What I want, it's to display the "id_domicile" and "id_exterieur" :

- Expected: id_match - home_nom - away_nom - team_nom - score_home - score_away

My try :

```
SELECT 
    resultat_world.id_match,
    team_home.nom AS home_nom, 
    team_away.nom AS away_nom,
    team.nom AS team_winner, 
    resultat_world.score_home,
    resultat_world.score_away
  FROM 
    resultat_world,match_world
  INNER JOIN 
    teams_world AS team_home 
    ON match_world.id_domicile = team_home.id_equipe 
  INNER JOIN 
    teams_world AS team_away 
    ON match_world.id_exterieur = team_away.id_equipe
  INNER JOIN 
  teams_world AS team 
    ON resultat_world.id_equipe_winner = team.id_equipe
```

Someone can explain me where is my problem ?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably getting an `#1054 - Unknown column 'resultat_world.id_equipe_winner' in 'on clause'` error.

This is because you're using a comma (implicit cross join) in your `FROM` clause, which has a lower precedence than the `INNER JOIN`s. The `INNER JOIN`s are then calculated before the comma in the `FROM` clause, so when the `INNER JOIN` to the `teams_world AS team` table is calculated, the `resultat_world.id_equipe_winner` column does not exist yet. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54738895/3960296

Fix by either adding parentheses to calculate the implicit cross join first:

```
  FROM 
    (resultat_world,match_world)
```

Or use the explicit cross join syntax which does the same without the need for parentheses:

```
  FROM 
    resultat_world CROSS JOIN match_world
```

Both select all of the rows from the `resultat_world` table, and then combine each of those rows with all of the rows from the `match_world` table (cartesian product).

For your desired result you probably want to add a `WHERE` clause to only keep those rows where the `id_match` of the `resultat_world` row matches the `id_match` of the `match_world` row:

```
SELECT 
    resultat_world.id_match,
    team_home.nom AS home_nom, 
    team_away.nom AS away_nom,
    team.nom AS team_winner, 
    resultat_world.score_home,
    resultat_world.score_away
  FROM 
    (resultat_world,match_world)
  INNER JOIN 
    teams_world AS team_home 
    ON match_world.id_domicile = team_home.id_equipe 
  INNER JOIN 
    teams_world AS team_away 
    ON match_world.id_exterieur = team_away.id_equipe
  INNER JOIN 
  teams_world AS team 
    ON resultat_world.id_equipe_winner = team.id_equipe
    
WHERE resultat_world.id_match = match_world.id_match
```

You can get the same result with an `INNER JOIN`, this is the recommended approach (do not use cross joins):

```
SELECT 
    resultat_world.id_match,
    team_home.nom AS home_nom,
    team_away.nom AS away_nom,
    team.nom AS team_winner,
    resultat_world.score_home,
    resultat_world.score_away

FROM 
    resultat_world
INNER JOIN
    match_world
    ON resultat_world.id_match = match_world.id_match

INNER JOIN
    teams_world AS team_home 
    ON match_world.id_domicile = team_home.id_equipe
INNER JOIN
    teams_world AS team_away 
    ON match_world.id_exterieur = team_away.id_equipe
INNER JOIN
    teams_world team
    ON resultat_world.id_equipe_winner = team.id_equipe
```

Hope this helps!