# Laravel Eloquent - 2 seperate table with own left join

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have the following 4 tables

```
aa:id, xx_id, bb_id
bb:id
xx:id, zz_id
zz.id
```

I would like to do a query like this

```sql
SELECT *
FROM
    aa LEFT JOIN bb ON (aa.bb_id = bb.id),
    xx LEFT JOIN zz ON (xx.zz_id = zz.id)
WHERE aa.xx_id = xx.id
```

How do I achieve this through Laravel Eloquent?

Answer (score 0):

[Since using a comma to separate tables in the `FROM` clause is the same as using a `CROSS JOIN`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3918570), you should first rewrite your query to use a CROSS JOIN.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM
    (SELECT * FROM aa LEFT JOIN bb ON aa.bb_id = bb.id) T1
CROSS JOIN
    (SELECT * FROM xx LEFT JOIN zz ON xx.zz_id = zz.id) T2
WHERE
    aa.xx_id = xx.id
```

```php
// First define the subqueries.
$t1 = DB::table('aa')->leftJoin('bb', 'aa.bb_id', 'bb.id');
$t2 = DB::table('xx')->leftJoin('zz', 'xx.zz_id', 'zz.id');
// Do the query.
$results = DB::table($t1, 'T1')
    ->crossJoinSub($t2, 'T2')
    ->whereColumn('aa.x_id', 'xx.id')
    ->get();
```

Alternatively, you can pass the whole `FROM` clause to the `fromRaw` method.

```php
$results = DB::query()
    ->fromRaw('aa LEFT JOIN bb ON (aa.bb_id = bb.id), xx LEFT JOIN zz ON (xx.zz_id = zz.id)')
    ->whereColumn('aa.x_id', 'xx.id')
    ->get();
```