# SQL Server - why does order of tables in from matter?

Tags: sql-server

Admittedly am not an expert in SQL so this might be a very basic query .
Was tasked with converting existing SQL in Oracle to SQL server .

When I first ran the following SQL in SQL server :

```
SELECT DISTINCT o.ext_org_type_cd,
                scbc.CODE_DESCR
FROM   dbo.emp_type t,
       dbo.emp_org o,
       dbo.emp_code c
       LEFT JOIN dbo.ZONE_CODE scbc
              ON scbc.CODE_TYPE = 'COUNTRY'
                 AND o.EXT_ORG_COUNTRY = scbc.CODE_ID
WHERE  o.ext_org_type_cd = t.ext_org_type_cd;
```

It failed with an error :

> SQL Error [4104] [S0001]: The multi-part identifier "o.EXT_ORG_COUNTRY" could not be bound.

Then I changed it to :

```
SELECT DISTINCT o.ext_org_type_cd,
                scbc.CODE_DESCR
FROM   dbo.emp_type t,
       dbo.emp_code c,
       dbo.emp_org o
       LEFT JOIN dbo.ZONE_CODE scbc
              ON scbc.CODE_TYPE = 'COUNTRY'
                 AND o.EXT_ORG_COUNTRY = scbc.CODE_ID
WHERE  o.ext_org_type_cd = t.ext_org_type_cd;
```

and this ran successfully  ( Notice that `dbo.emp_org o` is now the last table in from clause )

so I am not sure why the order in from matters .
It is definitely related to the LEFT JOIN `and o.EXT_ORG_COUNTRY  = scbc.CODE_ID`

Is there a way I can write the LEFT JOIN without the need of changing table order in from clause ?

Comment: Using the [old join syntax](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) is bad enough on its own; mixing it with the new join syntax is even worse. In the first case you are joining emp_code and ZONE_CODE, in the second emp_org and ZONE_CODE. Rewrite your query using joins only and your questions will disappear.

Comment: comma has different precedence https://stackoverflow.com/a/54738895/73226 - but you should definitely just use `INNER JOIN` instead of `,` here. That will also fix the probably accidental cross join to `emp_code` - which has no join condition specified in either query

Comment: It's actually some what confusing that you're mixing ANSI-89 and ANSI-92 JOIN syntax. Is it because nothing after SQL Server 2008 supports the 34 year old syntax for outer joins?

Comment: @GSerg For some reason still remains very popular with Oracle coders, despite being way out of date.